# Insert value to MySQL Database if not exist using Python(PyMySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, pymysql

I am trying to Fetch value from an existing database and also insert the value into the database if not exist.

This code works fine to fetch the value the value but **I am not able to insert the value into database..**

```
    import pymysql
    connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    db='chatbotqad',
    )
    user_input=input('Enter :')
    print(user_input)
    try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = "SELECT * FROM `qans` WHERE `Questions` = ('%s') " % user_input
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        if not cursor.fetchone():
            sqli = "INSERT INTO `qans` VALUES (%s)" % user_input
            cursor.execute(sqli) 

        print("Que\t\t Answer")            
        print("-------------------------")            
        for row in result:
            print(str(row[0]) + "\t\t" + row[1])


    except:
        print("Oops! Something wrong")
    connection.commit()
    finally:
    connection.close()**strong text**
```

Comment: This code is prone to **race conditions**, ideally you should also add a unique key in your table and also you should do this in one query more or less like `INSERT INTO <table> <columns> SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <condition>` .. See the MySQL manual how to use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT ...`  [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Can you see whether the insert statement is running - e.g. place a `print()` statement before `cursor.execute(sqli) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found this solution.

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    db='chatbotqad',
)

user_input=input('Enter input:')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT * FROM `qans` WHERE `Questions` = ('%s') " % user_input

        try:
            if (cursor.execute(sql)==0):
                result = cursor.fetchall()

                Ans_input=input('Please enter Answer:-')
                sql = "INSERT INTO `qans` (Questions, Answers) VALUES (%s,%s)"

                try:
                    cursor.execute(sql, (user_input,Ans_input))
                    print("Task added successfully")
                except:
                    print("Oops! Something wrong")

            else:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                print("Que\t\t Answer")
                print("-------------------------")
                for row in result:
                     print(str(row[0]) + "\t\t" + row[1])
        except:
            print("Oops! Something wrong")

    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```